# PostBack Asp.Net WebForms

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, webforms

Comecei a pouco tempo a trabalhar com `WebForms` e ficou uma dúvida, devido a sempre mexer com o `asp.net mvc`.

Supondo que tenho um `DropDownList` e populei o `DataSource` dele com vários registros, quando realizado o `PostBack` eu não consigo recuperar os dados que constam nesse `DropDownList`, tem alguma forma de recuperar esses dados? qual a melhor forma de trabalhar com os dados em `PostBack` . Obrigado.

```
    private void PopularEmpresasDoGrupoDoUsuario()
    {
        VOB2BUser voUser = GetSessionUser();
        DAOB2BCompany daoCompany = new DAOB2BCompany(((Page)Page).DATABASE);
        DAOB2BUser daoUser = new DAOB2BUser(((Page)Page).DATABASE);
        DAOB2BCompanyGroupUser daoCompanyGroupUser = new DAOB2BCompanyGroupUser(((Page)Page).DATABASE);

        var userGroup = daoCompanyGroupUser.GetUserGroup(voUser.IdUser);
        if (userGroup == null)
        {
            divEmpresasDoGrupoDoUsuario.Visible = false;
        }
        else
        {
            divEmpresasDoGrupoDoUsuario.Visible = true;

            dropDownListEmpresasDoGrupoDoUsuario.DataSource = daoCompany.GetEmpresasVinculadasNoGrupoDeEmpresa(userGroup.IdGroup);
            dropDownListEmpresasDoGrupoDoUsuario.DataBind();

            upEmpresasDoGrupoDoUsuario.Update();

            dropDownListEmpresasDoGrupoDoUsuario.SelectedIndex = 0;
            dropDownListEmpresasDoGrupoDoUsuario_SelectedIndexChanged(dropDownListEmpresasDoGrupoDoUsuario, new EventArgs());
        }
    }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (!this.Page.IsPostBack)
        {                
            if (Session["USER"] != null)
            {                    
                PopularEmpresasDoGrupoDoUsuario();
                SetUserPermissions(fc);
            }
        }            
    }
```

Comment: você quer que, ao selecionar o item no dropdown, ele realiza o postback e vc pegue o valor que foi selecionado ?

Comment: @RovannLinhalis, não amigo, quero saber como trabalho com todos os dados que foram carregados nesse DropDownList, vamos supor, ao realizar o postback, eu pegar tudo que tem no datasource dele e trabalhar com esses registros, entende? Só vejo um jeito de trabalhar com isso, jogando num ViewState, mas sei que não é uma boa prática, gostaria de saber se tem algum outro jeito de fazer isso!

Comment: e, o postback pode ser disparado de várias formas diferentes, algum controle específico pra vc tratar isso ? ou seria em todos os postbacks que ocorrerem na pagina ?

Comment: @RovannLinhalis, estou desenvolvendo uma rotina que vou precisar pegar em todo postback da pagina os dados e realizar um filtro nele para achar o registro que preciso, ou seja, vou pegar esses dados em todos postbacks.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode, em todo evento Load da página, verificar se é um postback ou não. E então pegar os dados que estão no source do dropdown. Exemplo:

> Utilizei um DataTable como exemplo

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    if (!this.IsPostBack)
    {
          //Não é postback
    }
    else
    {
         DataTable dt  = dropDownList1.DataSource as DataTable;
         if (dt != null)
         {
            //Faz o que precisa com o DataTable
         } 
    }
}
```

> ps. Cuidado, pois o código será executado em todo o postback que acontecer, pode afetar consideravelmente o desempenho.

Comment: Então, eu tentei realizar dessa forma, mas o datasource dele vem null, imagino eu que é devido ao postback.

Comment: o dropdown é preenchido de q forma ?

Comment: Vou editar o post colocando o código.

Comment: Da uma olhada @Rovann

Comment: já tentou armazenar em uma Session ?

Comment: Sim, exatamente essa é minha dúvida, dizem que não é muito bom ficar guardado dados em Session ou até mesmo em ViewState, só gostaria de saber mesmo se existe alguma outra saída sem ser essa, pois achei estranho o C# não mandar os dados nos postbacks, pelo menos do componente que está realizando o postback. Mas pelo que estou vendo não tem outra saída a não ser trabalhar com Session ou ViewState né ?

Comment: pois é, sinceramente faz tempo que não mexo com webforms, e não lembro se já fiz algo assim, mas nunca tive problemas em trabalhar com dados do dropdown. Mas enfim, espero que consiga resolver, e se não for muitos dados, que venham a prejudicar a aplicação, manda na session mesmo. vlw

Comment: Nesse caso seria melhor ViewStates né? Pois pelo menos elas são destruídas quando trocada a página.